# Filter dict results in TypeError

Tags: python

Following code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#timedelta
timedelta = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=6)

# YY/mm/dd H:M:S
delta_string = timedelta.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

test_data = {'test1': {'timestamp': '2023/02/11 19:03:51.000'}, 'test2' : {'timestamp': '2023/02/11 19:03:51.000'}}

print(test_data)

test_data = [test_data[n] for n in test_data if test_data[n]['timestamp'] > delta_string]

print(test_data)
```

This seems to filter correctly but I don't get the full dict in return.

I'm trying to filter a "simplified" dict based on timestamp. I noticed that I probably do a list comprehension instead dict. However, if I change the code to

`test_data = {test_data[n] for n in test_data if test_data[n]['timestamp'] > delta_string}`

I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

I do need to return the full dict minus the filtered values.

Comment: You forgot to add a key. `{n: test_data[n] for n ...}`. Without the key specifier `:`, the curly brace comprehensions make `set` instances, which is why you are getting the error about hashing.

Comment: Could also use `items` to simplify this. `{k: v for k, v in test_data.items() if v['timestamp'] > delta_string}`

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and to make a [mre]. Here, the datetime aspect of the question is irrelevant to the problem, so it'd be simpler to use another data type like ints for example, especially something that's not dependent on the current time/date.

Comment: @wjandrea True, hope you like it better now :-) But changing the data type makes no sense too in my mind

Comment: @flakes Thank you, that solves the puzzle. I'm obviously fairly new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You are next to the correct answer - You don't assign a value to the key of the dict. Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#timedelta
timedelta = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=6)

# YY/mm/dd H:M:S
delta_string = timedelta.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

test_data = {'test1': {'timestamp': '2023/02/11 19:03:51.000'}, 'test2' : {'timestamp': '2023/02/11 19:03:51.000'}}

print(test_data)

test_data = {n: test_data[n] for n in test_data if test_data[n]['timestamp'] > delta_string}
# or
test_data2 = {k: v for k, v in test_data.items() if v['timestamp'] > delta_string}

print(test_data)
print(test_data2)
```

Comment: Thank you but already answered in the comments by @flakes